¿Como guardar datos de un input dinamico en JavaScript?
Estoy tratando de crear un listado dinámico en JavaScript que me permita ingresar los datos de una persona (nombre y nota) de forma dinámica.
Logré hacerlo a través de prompts, pero no es muy dinámico que digamos. Así que intenté hacerlo a través de inputs, mas solo me guarda el primer input y los demás los ignora.
¿Alguien me podría ayudar a ver que estoy haciendo mal?


const contenedor = document.querySelector('#estudiante');
const agregar = document.querySelector('#add');
var numAlum = 0;
let name = [""];
let grade = [0];
let status = [""];

agregar.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" required> <input type="text" id="grade" placeholder="Ingrese la nota"><button onclick="addAlum(this)">Añadir</button>';
  contenedor.appendChild(div);
})

const addAlum = (e) => {
  name[numAlum] = document.getElementById("name").value;
  grade[numAlum] = document.getElementById("grade").value;
  grade[numAlum] = parseInt(grade[numAlum]);
  if (grade[numAlum] >= 10 && grade[numAlum] <= 20)
    status[numAlum] = 'Aprobado';
  else
    status[numAlum] = 'Reprobado';
  document.write(name[numAlum], " ");
  document.write(grade[numAlum], " ");
  document.write(status[numAlum], "<br>");
  numAlum++;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Registro Estudiantes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Registro de estudiantes</h1>
  <form>
    <div id="estudiante">
      <button id="add">Iniciar</button>
      <script src="Script.js"></script>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>




No entiendo el problema

Si buscas que los campos aparezcan una única vez y se vayan agregando los datos que se inserten en los campos, te dejo esta propuesta.
Si no es el resultado que esperas, deja un comentario.


const contenedor = document.querySelector('#estudiante');
const resultados = document.querySelector('#resultados');

const addAlum = (e) => {
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let grade = parseInt(document.getElementById("grade").value);
  let status = "";
  if (grade >= 10 && grade <= 20) {
    status = 'Aprobado';
  } else {
    status = 'Reprobado';
  }
  //Mostrar el listado de alumnos
  let alumno = document.createElement("p");
  alumno.innerHTML = `${name} ${grade} ${status}`;
  resultados.appendChild(alumno);
  //Limpiar los campos
  document.getElementById("name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("grade").value = "";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Registro Estudiantes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Registro de estudiantes</h1>
  <div id="estudiante">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" required>
    <input type="text" id="grade" placeholder="Ingrese la nota" required>
    <button onclick="addAlum(this)">Añadir</button>
  </div>
  <div id="resultados">
    
  </div>
  <!-- El script va fuera del div, siempre antes de cerrar la etiqueta body -->
  <script src="Script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




Es justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!

Es con todo el gusto. Recuerda darle un voto positivo a la respuesta para que sea de utilidad para futuros visitantes y de paso ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad.
